# Get maximum value over multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

In my SQLite database, in each table, there is a `sync_id` column. I regularly want to retrieve the maximum `sync_id` for each table. Here's what I tried first:

```
SELECT
    MAX(answer.sync_id),
    MAX(community.sync_id),
    MAX(question.sync_id),
    MAX(topic.sync_id)
FROM
    answer,
    community,
    question,
    topic;
```

This query took forever, I actually never got to the end of it.

Here's what I tried next:

```
SELECT "answer" AS name, MAX(answer.sync_id) AS max_sync_id FROM answer
    UNION SELECT "community" AS name, MAX(community.sync_id) AS max_sync_id FROM community
    UNION SELECT "question" AS name, MAX(question.sync_id) AS max_sync_id FROM question
    UNION SELECT "topic" AS name, MAX(topic.sync_id) AS max_sync_id FROM topic;
```

This one is blazingly fast and gives me the results I expected.

---

I have 2 questions about this:

- Why are the 2 queries so different? I'm guessing there's some SQL semantics that I'm not getting, some kind of implicit JOIN...
- The 1st query returns the maximums as one row, with columns named after the tables. The 2nd query returns 1 maximum per row, and I had to create a `name` column to keep the context. Is there a way I could get the result set of the 1st query, with the speed of the 2nd query?

Comment: You are asking why `UNION` is different from `CROSS JOIN`.  You need to learn the basics of SQL.  This should be covered in any tutorial or book on the subject.

Comment: I understand why they're different. I just didn't know the semantics of the comma (which apparently is a `CROSS JOIN`, something I know now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1/ Why are the queries so different

Because the first one makes a big table as the cartesian product of the 4 tables before running the `select` against it, while the second one fires 1 request per table before aggregating the results in 4 lines. The execution plan of both requests can show that in details.

## 2/ Is there a way to get the result set of the 1st query with the speed of the 2nd query?

No. This is because of the nature of your data: seems like your 4 tables are not related anyhow, so you can't have a single (fast) request to hit them all. The best would probably be to make 4 requests, and group your results in your application.